# Web driver is not performing actions on web page

Tags: java, php, selenium, web

I'm automating a php web page using webdriver and  java language. My code was executing and I was able to perform actions on web page, but today only the login method is executing and my second method gets failed everytime I run. I'm so worried why it is happening. Please help, I'm new in automation testing.

```
 public class TestNGClass {

private String baseUrl = "http://test.com/test2/1.4.6.3/public/admin/";
private WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


@Test
    public void login() {
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("abc");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("123");
    driver.findElement(By.name("login")).submit();
    System.out.print("\nCongrats..You have successfully logged in.");
    }
```

@Test
        public void createUser() {

```
    String expectedTitle = "User";
    String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
    Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle,"Title Not Found!");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a/img")).click();
```

Error :

java.lang.AssertionError: Title Not Found! expected [User] but found []

Comment: Usually when things "just stop working" it's usually a compatibility thing. What version of Firefox and Selenium are you using? It's possible Firefox auto-upgraded without you knowing it. So this should be the first port of call to debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using Assert.

```
Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle,"Title Not Found!");
```

Make use of Try catch in-order to proceed next step.

```
try{
Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle,"Title Not Found!");
}catch (Exception e)
{
}
```